# Silex - Twig_Error_Syntax: The function "path" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

According to the [Silex documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/twig.html#symfony2-components-integration):

> Symfony provides a Twig bridge that provides additional integration between some Symfony2 components and Twig. Add it as a dependency to your composer.json file.

I include the following in my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "1.*",
        "twig/twig": ">=1.8,<2.0-dev",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "2.3.*"
    }
}
```

I register the `TwigServiceProvider()` like so:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__ . '/views'
));
```

I'm attempting to use the twig `path()` method like so:

```
<a href="{{ path('logout') }}">Log out</a>
```

The error I get is as follows:

> Twig_Error_Syntax: The function "path" does not exist

**Why am I getting this error?**

- I have tried switching around versions to check if it is a version issue
- One google groups comment suggested 'registering' the twig bridge provider, but this doesn't exist
- I *don't* want to have to use: `app.url_generator.generate` in all my templates instead

---

### A temporary solution I have found:

Ensure The `UrlGeneratorServiceProvider()` is registered:

```
$app->register(new UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());
```

Create a new function for twig for `path()`:

```
$app['twig']->addFunction(new \Twig_SimpleFunction('path', function($url) use ($app) {
    return $app['url_generator']->generate($url);
}));
```

**I shouldn't have to do this!!** How can I get this working *properly*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hopefully this will help future viewers as many have posted this question without a solid answer, so here is one.

**It is literally that you need `UrlGeneratorServiceProvider()` registered**

```
$app->register(new UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());
```

**Also**, as umpirsky mentions in the comments, you need `symfony/twig-bridge` installed via composer.

You do not need to add your own function. You need both the `TwigServiceProvider()` *and* the `UrlGeneratorServiceProvider()` registered before loading your twig template. This isn't easily apparent from the documentation.

Comment: This is not the only requirement. You should register both the Twig and UrlGenerator before executing anything like `$app['twig']->addGlobal('layout', $app['twig']->loadTemplate('layout.twig'));`. Inserting this before registering UrlGenerator may cause the path() method not registered.

Comment: @VyacheslavPetrov Nowhere whatsoever does my codebase use your above described code. I feel it isn't relevant to the issue at hand. Also, it's pretty obvious that before trying to retrieve an object from the pimple DiC, trying to access said object would error.

Comment: Googled for the question asked, this answer doesn't work. I have registered both UrlGeneratorServiceProvider and TwigServiceProvider, but the path function still doesn't exist when rendering twig templates.

Comment: @Drarok You must be doing something different. I suggest starting with a brand new clean version and trying there - it worked for 5 other users.

Comment: Note that also `symfony/twig-bridge` need to be installed, because of https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/TwigServiceProvider.php#L54

Answer (score 0):

I too had to create a new function for twig for `path()`, but I improved it a bit to handle a variable number of arguments to allow passing arrays in the twig template:

```
$app['twig']->addFunction(new \Twig_SimpleFunction('path', function(...$url) use ($app) {
   return call_user_func_array(array($app['url_generator'], 'generate'), $url);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Four easy steps.

1. Create the loader
2. Create the twig object.
3. Create you custom function
4. Add to the Twig object.

```
    use Twig\Environment;
    use Twig\TwigFunction;
    use Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader;

    $loader = new FilesystemLoader('/twig/templates');
    $twig = new Environment($loader, []);

    $function = new TwigFunction('url', function () { return 'MyURL'; });
    $twig -> addFunction($function);
```