# Twig generate url / Routing error / Function unknow

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

I'm  using Silex 1.2 and Twig 1.0.

I'm trying to generate an URL with Twig.

`<a href="{{ path('signUp') }}">Sign Up</a>`

However I get this error :

**Twig_Error_Syntax** `Unknown "path" function.`

So, like on this post ([Silex - Twig_Error_Syntax: The function "path" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092585/silex-twig-error-syntax-the-function-path-does-not-exist)) I added this on my `boostrap.php`.

```
$app->register(new UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());
$app['twig']->addFunction(new \Twig_SimpleFunction('path', function($url) use ($app) {
    return $app['url_generator']->generate($url);
}));
```

But I get this error :

**RouteNotFoundException** `Unable to generate a URL for the named route "signUp" as such route does not exist.`

**Routing file**

```
<?php

$routes = $app['controllers_factory'];

$routes->get('/', function () use ($app){
    return $app['twig']->render('home.html.twig');
});

$routes->get('/signUp', function () use ($app){
    return $app['twig']->render('signUp.html.twig');
});

$routes->get('/signIn', function () use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('signIn.html.twig');
});

return $routes;
```

Can you help me ?

Thank's !

Comment: You didn't give your routes names. See the [examples](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/1.3/providers/url_generator.html) regarding the `bind()` method.

Comment: Indeed, thank's a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path `/signUp` is not the same as the route name you provide in path. You probable want a [named route](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/1.3/usage.html#named-routes) using `bind` like this:

```
$routes->get('/signUp', function () use ($app){
    return $app['twig']->render('signUp.html.twig');
})->bind('signUp');
```

Comment: Yes that's was the problem. Thank's !

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to `config/services.yaml` solved it for me:

```
services:
    Twig\Environment:
        calls:
            - [addExtension, ['@Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension']]

    Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension:
```